# MySQL server log swarms with "Aborted connection (...) (Got an error reading communication packets)" when using Mikro-ORM/Knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js, mikro-orm

I'm using MikroORM v5.7.10 with Knex v2.4.2.
There is a connection pool that looks like: `{min: 0, max: 10}`.
From the application point of view, everything seems to be fine - no errors related to MikroORM/MySQL/Knex are reported but the server gets a lot of logs that look like this:

```
Aborted connection 12863 to db: 'XXXXXX' user: 'YYYYYYY' host: 'ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ' (Got an error reading communication packets). (sql_connect.cc:845).
```

I'm not sure if that's related to anything but the database is AWS Aurora running MySQL 8.

I've read that knex was doing something like this in the past as part of `generic-pool`'s behavior but that's supposed to be a history right now:

https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2041

I'd like to get rid of those errors from database's log but I don't want to hide an actul problem in the process (if there is a problem I shoulld be handling somehow).